# HTML Entities (for e.g. &int) are getting decoded as symbols in JSF Backing Bean

Tags: jsf, encoding, html-entities

I have a JSF hInputTextBox with takes URLs are input and saves it into a DB table on click of a submit button.

In the backing bean handler for submit button, I try to read the value in hInputTextBox using request.getParameter("httpUrl"). It works fine for almost all URLs except the one which has content resembling to HTML entities.

hInputText value= "http://ww.jk.com?t=t&interface=k"

BackingBean code:

```
  FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context
                .getExternalContext().getRequest();
   String httpUrl = request.getParameter("httUrl")
```

Value in httpUrl = http://ww.jk.com?t=t∫erface=k

If you see, the &interface=k part is changed to ∫erface=k , where &int (with a semi-colon ideally) is the HTML code for ∫ symbol.

How can I get the URL value as it is?

Regards,
Anoop

Comment: why are you trying to read an `h:inputText` (assuming that is what you use) via request.getParameter(...)?

Comment: The form which contains this h:inputText is kind of dynamic. i.e. I do not have a fixed set of input texts. So, cannot bind one field to backing bean member directly using getters/setters.

Comment: You can bind to a list with Strings or a hashmap... Way easier. If you read a request parameter, you have to make sure (on the client side) that it is encoded in the correct way (at least that is what I suspect)

Comment: If I check the outgoing request via Chrome Debugger, I can see the value is proper (&interface). So, it must be getting tampered at the sever side? Also, shouldn't it leave the &interface "as-is", since it is not ending with a semi-colon ( to consider it something special) ?

Comment: JSF doesn't do anything with them here. Your problem is caused elsewhere.

Comment: Hi BalusC , any pointers on where I should look?